# Trample and double strike

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I attack with an 8/8 double strike trampler.  My opponent blocks with a 3/5, and three 1/2 creatres.  How much damage does my opponent ultimately receive?  I said 5, he said 4. Who is correct?  Thanks

Comment: Why do you think the answer is 5? Did your opponent provide the reasoning for why they think the answer is 4?

Comment: @murgatroid99 The disconnect probably comes from the opponent not accounting for the 1 damage done to a 1/2 during the first combat damage step, thus believing that 1/2 needs 2 damage assigned to it during the second combat damage step to do lethal damage.

Comment: Yeah, I also suspect that that's the issue. It's a weird option, though, because you can just shuffle some creatures around, say that you're not accounting for the 3 damage done to the 3/5 during the first combat damage step, and end up with just 3 damage done to the player.

Comment: @murgatroid99: It makes sense if they simply overlooked the fact that damage remains on a creature until end of turn.

Answer (score 4):

**Your opponent will be dealt up to 5 damage**

Damage doesn't wear off until end of turn, so it's irrelevant how much damage a creature is dealt in the First Strike or normal combat damage segment individually.

> 119.6. Damage marked on a creature remains until the cleanup step (...)

Therefore, when dealing with a creature with Trample, you can simply add up the defense of all creatures blocking it, subtract that number from the trampling creature's total power (multiplied by 2, if it has Double Strike) and end up with the amount of damage dealt to the player. In this case, here's what the calculation looks like:

```
8 * 2 - (5 + 2 + 2 + 2)  =  16 - 11  =  5
```

Exceptions to this rule would be the creature with Double Strike dieing in the First Strike combat damage segment, for example when blocked by a [Glissa, the Traitor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlissa%2c%20the%20Traitor%5d). Since the blocking creatures in this case aren't capable of dealing lethal damage in the First Strike combat damage step, damage assignment order and combat damage segments are irrelevant to this specific example.

*Note that you can assign more damage to a blocking creature than it has toughness, meaning you could assign all damage to the blocking creatures and none to the defending player. Because of that, the answer is phrased "up to 5 damage"*

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was a FNM.  I probably should have called a judge, oh well.